# Query Mongoose model not of a particular field type

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose

I will like to query a model using mongoose where type is not of type array. I had to change one of the fields of my model (lastSeen) from a date type to an array of dates. I now need to query previous documents that still have their lastSeen as date. I can easily make a query which is of type "date", but how do I query the field which are **not of type array?**

```js
const users = await User.find({lastSeen: {$type: "date", $exists: true}});
```

Note that the query above returns both documents having their type as array of dates and those of just dates

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$not`

```
const users = await User.find({lastseen:{$not:{$type:"array"}}})
```